# turning all id's into a table to its value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables Table contacts and Table companies.
In table contact there's 4 columns called company id(1-4)
in these columns there's the company id(s) that the person is associated with.
now the problem is that instead of the id i want to be able to display the company name i tried it with the following query but it only gives me values of the last row

```
select *
from contact as ct
 join company as cy1 on cy1.Company_id = ct.Company_id1
 join company as cy2 on cy2.Company_id = ct.Company_id2
 join company as cy3 on cy3.Company_id = ct.Company_id2
 join company as cy4 on cy4.Company_id = ct.Company_id4


$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ) );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$stmtcount = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
if ($stmtcount > 0) {
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                                    $id = $row['Contact_id'];
                                    $fname = $row['Firstname'];
                                    $lname = $row['Lastname'];                                       
                                    $company1=$row['Company'];
                                    $company2=$row['Company'];
                                    $company3=$row['Company'];
                                    $company4=$row['Company'];



echo '<tr>';
echo "<td> <a class='notice' href='details.php?id=" . $id . " '>" .$row['Abbreviation'].'&nbsp'. $row['Firstname'] . "</a> </td>";

echo '<td>'.$lname.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$company1.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$company2.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$company3.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$company4.'</td>';

echo '</tr>';
```

the results are as follows [result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGBKF.png)
the table structure

[and here's the database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aFB9.png)

Comment: You've tagged both mysql and sql-server - which is it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql-server srry for that i added it in the tags

Answer (score 0):

Try using column aliases instead of `select *`:

```
select ct.*,
       cy1.name as name1,
       cy2.name as name2,
       cy3.name as name3,
       cy4.name as name4
from contact ct join
     company cy1
     on cy1.Company_id = ct.Company_id1 join
     company
     cy2
     on cy2.Company_id = ct.Company_id2 join
     company cy3
     on cy3.Company_id = ct.Company_id2 join
     company cy4
     on cy4.Company_id = ct.Company_id4;
```

If multiple columns have the same name, then the query will arbitrary choose one value.

Comment: im a bit confused can you please explain  why i would select ct.* if i dont have a table called ct same for cy1.name as name1

Comment: @RocheandleyKwidama . . . `ct` is a table alias.  It is the first alias defined in the `from` clause.